# Loop Through Stock Tickers and Creat List of all Charts

Tags: r

How can I loop through stock tickers, copy each to some kind of report, such as a PDF file, and save the report?  The script below loops through a bunch of tickers, but it overwrites each previous chart with the next chart.  I want to list the next chart under the previous chart, and list everything in a PDF, or Word document.

```
library(quantmod)
stocks <- c("FIS", "AXP", "AVB")
stockEnv <- new.env()
symbols <- getSymbols(stocks, src='yahoo', env=stockEnv)
for (stock in ls(stockEnv)){
    chartSeries(stockEnv[[stock]], theme="white", name=stock,
        TA="addVo();addBBands();addCCI();addSMA(20, col='blue');
        addSMA(5, col='red');addSMA(50, col='black')", subset='last 30 days')     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling the pdf() function and turning the plotting device off after creating all charts using dev.off() worked for me:

```
library(quantmod)
stocks <- c("FIS", "AXP", "AVB")
stockEnv <- new.env()
symbols <- getSymbols(stocks, src='yahoo', env=stockEnv)

pdf('test.pdf')
for (stock in ls(stockEnv)){
  chartSeries(stockEnv[[stock]], theme="white", name=stock,
              TA="addVo();addBBands();addCCI();addSMA(20, col='blue');
        addSMA(5, col='red');addSMA(50, col='black')", subset='last 30 days')     
}
dev.off()
```

That code created a pdf document in my working directory called test.pdf. It had three plots, one plot per page.

Comment: That does work!!  I thought this line would go INSIDE the loop...
pdf('test.pdf')

I guess you just open and set the focus to the PDF and R writes to the active file.  Is that how it works?

Comment: Glad that helped! That's how i understand it. The pdf() call essentially tells R to output each subsequent plot from the plotting window into a desired pdf file. Once the device is turned off via dev.off(), R will no longer send plots to the pdf. So you call pdf(), generate all the plots which are sent to that pdf, then turn the device off. It's the same with jpeg() and png(). Also if your graphs come out pixelated, look into CairoPDF() in the Cairo package.